# How To Create a "Package Private" Android Application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to Android development and am trying to determine if there is a way to create an APK that is "package private".  I am trying to design a "portal" application that is both a store for app downloads and an exclusive launcher for the apps offered by my portal.  Is there a way I can configure the permissions on the individual APK manifests such that only my store can launch these apps?  I would also like to avoid making icons for the apps in the applications menu if possible.

So to summarize, I'm wondering if it is possible to make an app package that has no top-level icon and is only launchable by my portal.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I figured out the solution after digging around in the manifest documentation.  I removed all of the "intent-filter" entries in the subordinate application (thus making it private) and added a "sharedUserId" to both the portal app and the subordinate app.  Now I can launch it privately from my portal without having an icon in the application list for the subordinate app.

Sorry for the newb question- should have dug around farther before posting!

Comment: nice, a suggestion, post that as an answer and accept it so people with the same issue might find it.

Comment: I tried to and the server said I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question because I just made my profile.  I will officially answer it on Monday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution after digging around in the manifest documentation.  I removed all of the  entries in the subordinate application (thus making it private) and added a sharedUserId to both the portal app and the subordinate app.  Now I can launch it privately from my portal without having an icon in the application list for the subordinate app.